# How to convert CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress call to Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

Maybe I'm the first person doing this in Swift but there seems to be nothing on the net using &/inout together with uint8_t in Swift. Could someone translate this please? Is this relationship bitwise?

Objective-C

```
uint8_t *buf=(uint8_t *) CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cvimgRef);
```

Swift attempt

```
let inout buf:uint8_t = SOMETHING HERE CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cvimgRef)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress()` returns a `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>`,
which can be converted to an `UInt8` pointer via

```
let buf = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer))
```

**Update for Swift 3 (Xcode 8), Checked for Swift 5 (Xcode 11):**

```
if let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer) {
    let buf = baseAddress.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
    // `buf` is `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>`
} else {
    // `baseAddress` is `nil`
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I can see why you have 142k rep. I'll be posting questions like these all month long so please follow me! :) For `let buf` why don't we use the `inout` syntax like you showed me yesterday in my `func RGBtoHSV(r : Float, g : Float, b : Float, inout h : Float, inout s : Float, inout v : Float)`? Is `inout` only used in function arguments?

Comment: @Edward: Yes, `inout` is only used as a modifier for function parameters.

Comment: how to do you convert this `buf` UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> to an array of UInt8 ? ... [UInt8]

Comment: @omarojo: For example: `Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: buf, count: ...))`

Comment: say @MartinR , a few years on, what about this approach .. `let floatBfr = unsafeBitCast(CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pb), to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.self)`

Comment: @Fattie: From https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641250-unsafebitcast: “Do not use unsafeBitCast(_:to:) with class or pointer types; doing so may introduce undefined behavior.”