# DepthData - Get per-pixel depth data (CVPixelBuffer data analysis)

Tags: swift, ios11, cvpixelbuffer, iphone7plus

Now I run `AVDepthPhotoFilter` that Rendering Depth Deta from a stereo camera of iPhone7Plus.

So, I want to access per-pixel depth data, but, I don’t know how to do it. Please advice.

Answer (score 11):

**How to get DepthData and analysis CVPixelBuffer data**

1. You need to make sure your AVCapturePhotoSettings() has isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = true
2. You have to use the function *func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?)*

   ```
   func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {

       //## Convert Disparity to Depth ##

       let depthData = (photo.depthData as AVDepthData!).converting(toDepthDataType: kCVPixelFormatType_DepthFloat32)
       let depthDataMap = depthData.depthDataMap //AVDepthData -> CVPixelBuffer

       //## Data Analysis ##

       // Useful data
       let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(depthDataMap) //768 on an iPhone 7+
       let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(depthDataMap) //576 on an iPhone 7+
       CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(depthDataMap, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

       // Convert the base address to a safe pointer of the appropriate type
       let floatBuffer = unsafeBitCast(CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(depthDataMap), to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float32>.self)

       // Read the data (returns value of type Float)
       // Accessible values : (width-1) * (height-1) = 767 * 575

       let distanceAtXYPoint = floatBuffer[Int(x * y)]

   }
   ```

If you want more informations about CVPixelBuffer analysis, here is a useful post -> [details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34570127/5164509)

Comment: Helped me a lot.