How to get luma data of YpCbCr8BiPlanar CVPixelBuffer
I tried to get averageLuminance of a CVPixelBuffer, but this function crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS message after several rows of process.
I think I don't understand how to use Apple's YpCbCr8BiPlanar format.
this is my func. Any idea what I am doing wrong?
        func averageLuminance(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) -> Float? {
            guard CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(pixelBuffer) == kCVPixelFormatType_Lossy_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange else {
                print("Pixel buffer format mismatch.")
                return nil
            }
            
            CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, .readOnly)
            defer { CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, .readOnly) }
            
            guard let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0) else {
                print("Unable to get base address.")
                return nil
            }
            
            let lumaWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0)
            let lumaHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0)
            let lumaRowBytes = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0)
            
            var totalLuminance: Float = 0.0
            
            for row in 0..<lumaHeight {
                let rowBaseAddress = baseAddress.advanced(by: row * lumaRowBytes)
                let rowPointer = rowBaseAddress.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
                
                var rowSum: Float = 0.0
                for col in 0..<lumaWidth {
                    rowSum += Float(rowPointer[col])
                }
                
                let rowAverageLuminance = rowSum / Float(lumaWidth)
                totalLuminance += rowAverageLuminance
            }
            
            let averageLuminance = totalLuminance / Float(lumaHeight)
            
            return averageLuminance
        }


Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/57993883/833395 if it helps

Try to use let byteBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer(baseAddress), instead of rowPointer and row base address. And loop through Luma row width and Luma Height as you are doing. based on above comment link.

lossy type use less than 8bit to describe one pixel, so I uses non compressed type to avoid this problem
